# How to compare two List(of T) with compareTo() and save changes to a new List?

Tags: vb.net

I have converted 2 DataTables into 2 Lists and now I'm trying to compare them with a compareTo() function. Every row needs to be compared and if there are changes the objects should be added to a binding list and the changes should be transfered to an ultragrid and highlighted. "UANR" is primary key and i have to show if rows were deleted, added or modified.
The problem is that all rows i compare get added to the bindingList.

Base class with all the properties (columns):

```
Public MustInherit Class ISAACServiceBase


ReadOnly Property K_Art As String
ReadOnly Property UANR As String
ReadOnly Property Ueberbegriff As String
ReadOnly Property Benennung As String
ReadOnly Property Anzahl As Double
ReadOnly Property Einheit As String
ReadOnly Property Einzelkosten As Double
'ReadOnly Property Gesamtmenge As Integer
ReadOnly Property Summencode As String

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Sub New(kostenArt As String, uanr As String, ueberbegriff As String, benennung As String, anzahl As Double, einheit As String, einzelkosten As Double, sumcode As String)
    Me.K_Art = kostenArt
    Me.UANR = uanr
    Me.Ueberbegriff = ueberbegriff
    Me.Benennung = benennung
    Me.Anzahl = anzahl
    Me.Einheit = einheit
    Me.Einzelkosten = einzelkosten
    'Me.Gesamtmenge = gesamtmenge
    Me.Summencode = sumcode
End Sub
```

End Class

Here is the compareTo() function:

```
Public Function CompareTo(other As ISAACService) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of ISAACService).CompareTo

    If other.GetType() Is GetType(ISAACService) Then
        other = CType(other, ISAACService)

        If Me.UANR > other.UANR Then
            Return 1
        ElseIf Me.UANR < other.UANR Then
            Return -1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End If
    Return 0

End Function
```

This is how i convert datatable to a list:

```
Private Function ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable, lst As List(Of ISAACService)) As List(Of ISAACService)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        Dim ISAAC As New ISAACService(row(KostenArt).ToString, row(UANR).ToString, row(Ueberbegriff).ToString, row(Benennung).ToString, CDbl(row(Anzahl)), row(Einheit).ToString, CDbl(row(Einzelkosten)), row(Summencode).ToString)
        lst.Add(ISAAC)
        Next

        Return lst


End Function
```

And this is how i tried to go through both list and save the changes to a new List

```
Private Function CompareDataTables() As BindingList(Of ISAACService)
    'Beide Listen durchlaufen und vergleichen
    For Each item1 As ISAACService In lst1
        For Each item2 As ISAACService In lst2
            If item1.CompareTo(item2) = 1 Then
                resultList.Add(item1)
            ElseIf item1.CompareTo(item2) = -1 Then
                resultList.Add(item1)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return resultList
End Function
```

Update: I managed to get an empty list when i compare the same two ExcelSheets.

```
Private Function CompareDataTables() As BindingList(Of ISAACService)
    'Beide Listen durchlaufen und gleiche Zeilen löschen
    Dim lst3 = CombineLists(lst1, lst2)
    For Each s In lst3
        If lst1.Contains(s) Then
            lst1.Remove(s)
        ElseIf lst2.Contains(s) Then
            lst2.Remove(s)
        End If
    Next
    For Each item1 In lst1
        resultList.Add(item1)
    Next

    For Each item2 In lst2
        resultList.Add(item2)
    Next


    Return resultList
End Function
```

Now i need to include the compareTo-Method somehow, so that only rows with the same "UANR" get compared

Comment: *"The problem is that all rows i compare get added to the bindingList"*. That means that you're just looking at the end result and not the steps to get there. You need to debug your code and compare the actual behaviour to the logic you're trying to implement and see exactly where and how the two don't match up. If you can't tell us that, it's too soon to be posting a question here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I already tried to debug it.  It doesn't even go into one of the if statements in CompareDataTables() but it adds to the list anyway

Comment: What does it mean to you for one string to be greater than another string.?

Comment: What about the order of the 2 lists? Are they in the same order? Are the 2 lists the same length?

Comment: @Mary in my test case they are in the same order and same length, but it has to work with different length too.  If it has a different length it means a row has been deleted, added or both. Thats why i compare the "UANR". Does it even make sense to put the datatables into a list?

Answer (score 1):

Hash sets can do all sorts of interesting things. See if this might help reach your goal. If the result is not what you are looking for, check some of the other methods of HashSet.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst1 As New List(Of String) From {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John", "Paul"}
    Dim lst2 As New List(Of String) From {"John", "Peter", "Luke", "Saul", "Mark"}
    Dim lst3 = CombineLists(lst1, lst2)
    For Each s In lst3
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CombineLists(List1 As List(Of String), List2 As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    Dim hs1 = New HashSet(Of String)(List1)
    Dim hs2 = New HashSet(Of String)(List2)
    hs1.UnionWith(hs2)
    Dim lst = hs1.ToList
    Return lst
End Function
```

Result in Immediate Window

```
Mathew
Mark
Luke
John
Paul
Peter
Saul
```

Comment: That's a very good start, thank you. But i need the opposite: A list of objects that are not similar. I'm gonna look into the methods of HashSet or if i can make a workaround and share it here.

Comment: Updated my post.